# Generating Pop-up Help on input

Tags: javascript

I am working on a form and I am trying to generate help pop-up in case a user poorly fill an input field. Knowing fields have their own RegEx to control their validity, I want to generate the pop-up when the user click on its specific help-button.

I tried with a loop but I still have the uncaught error. I thought it was due to the querySelector, but even with a getElementById my function. Am I using the good way to create this event or maybe is there any method to link locally two HTML elements, I mean two elements inside the same div?

```
cart.js:172 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (cart.js:172)
```

This is my JS:

```
let z = document.querySelectorAll(".help-popup");
    for(let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        let getHelpPopUp = document.getElementById(`help-icon-${i}`);
        getHelpPopUp.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            let reachPopup = document.getElementById(`popup-${i}`);
            reachPopup.classList.toggle("show-popup");
            })
    }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="label-container">
    <label class="input-label letter-label" for="nom">Nom :</label>
    <i id="help-icon-1" class="help-icon __letter-input-help far fa-question-circle"></i>
    <input class="input-entry letter-input" id="input-nom" name="nom" type="text" required>
    <span class="help-popup" id="popup-1"> Pour ce champs veillez à n'utilisez que des lettres</span>
</div>

<div class="label-container">           
    <label class="input-label letter-label" for="prenom">Prénom :</label>
    <i id=""help-icon-2" class="help-icon __letter-input-help far fa-question-circle"></i>
    <input class="input-entry letter-input" id="input-prenom" name="prenom" type="text" required>
    <span class="help-popup" id="popup-2"> Pour ce champs veillez à n'utilisez que des lettres</span>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
    .help-icon{
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    grid-area: help;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.help-popup{
    grid-area: popup;
    border: solid;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-left: 10px;
    max-height: 2em;
    width: max-content;
}



.help-popup::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    right: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    top: 10%;
    border-color: transparent #555 transparent transparent; 
}


.show-popup{
    visibility: visible;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/*Animation Popup*/
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `i` of the for loop to construct your css selector `help-icon-${i}`. The `i` starts from zero and `help-icon-0` doesn't exists. That's why it can't read `addEventListener` from null because `getHelpPopUp` is null because it couldn't be found.

Try changing your loop to this, so it will start from 1:

```js
 for(let i = 1; i <= z.length; i++) {
```

Edit:

There also seems to be an extra qoute in your HTML `"`.
`<i id=""help-icon-2"` it should be `<i id="help-icon-2"`

How it looks after the changes and the CSS you added later
[Gif example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cI68.jpg)
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2bhyum98/13/)

Comment: Thanks for this, It solved the uncaught error. Still it doesnt the second popup when I click on the second help-button (it doesnt generate any popup)

Comment: @El_Michel You also have an extra qoute at the id part `<i id=""help-icon-2"` it should be  `<i id="help-icon-2"`. I tested the code and it seems to work now, the `show-popup` class get added when I click the help-icon. Try posting your CSS if it still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried and it still won't work on the second element. The event is not take into account on the second help icon

Comment: Here is an example of what I see when I change the for loop AND remove the dubbel `"` in the HTML [Gif of what I see](https://imgur.com/z3SCC8V) and a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/2bhyum98/13/) Is this what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for numbers staring at zero and not one. You also have an extra quote which messes up the attributes and it can not find the elements.

```js
let z = document.querySelectorAll(".help-popup");
for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
  console.log(`help-icon-${i+1}`)
  let getHelpPopUp = document.getElementById(`help-icon-${i+1}`);
  getHelpPopUp.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let reachPopup = document.getElementById(`popup-${i+1}`);
    reachPopup.classList.toggle("show-popup");
  })
}
```

```css
.help-icon {
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  grid-area: help;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.help-popup {
  grid-area: popup;
  border: solid;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: 10px;
  max-height: 2em;
  width: max-content;
}

.help-popup::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  right: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  top: 10%;
  border-color: transparent #555 transparent transparent;
}

.show-popup {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}


/*Animation Popup*/

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="label-container">
  <label class="input-label letter-label" for="nom">Nom :</label>
  <i id="help-icon-1" class="help-icon __letter-input-help far fa-question-circle"></i>
  <input class="input-entry letter-input" id="input-nom" name="nom" type="text" required>
  <span class="help-popup" id="popup-1"> Pour ce champs veillez à n'utilisez que des lettres</span>
</div>

<div class="label-container">
  <label class="input-label letter-label" for="prenom">Prénom :</label>
  <i id="help-icon-2" class="help-icon __letter-input-help far fa-question-circle"></i>
    <input class="input-entry letter-input" id="input-prenom " name="prenom" type="text " required>
    <span class="help-popup" id="popup-2"> Pour ce champs veillez à n'utilisez que des lettres</span>
</div>
```

Personally I would avoid all the looping and not add a bunch of event listeners. I would use event delegation and check to see if the help icon was clicked. If it was look for the pop up in that parent.

```js
document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
  const help = evt.target.closest('.help-icon');
  if (help) {
    help.closest('.label-container').querySelector('.help-popup').classList.toggle('show-popup');
  }
});
```

```css
.help-icon {
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  grid-area: help;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.help-popup {
  grid-area: popup;
  border: solid;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: 10px;
  max-height: 2em;
  width: max-content;
}

.help-popup::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  right: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  top: 10%;
  border-color: transparent #555 transparent transparent;
}

.show-popup {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}


/*Animation Popup*/

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="label-container">
    <label class="input-label letter-label" for="nom">Nom :</label>
    <i id="help-icon-1" class="help-icon __letter-input-help far fa-question-circle"></i>
    <input class="input-entry letter-input" id="input-nom" name="nom" type="text" required>
    <span class="help-popup" id="popup-1"> Pour ce champs veillez à n'utilisez que des lettres</span>
  </div>

  <div class="label-container">
    <label class="input-label letter-label" for="prenom">Prénom :</label>
    <i id="help-icon-2" class="help-icon __letter-input-help far fa-question-circle"></i>
    <input class="input-entry letter-input" id="input-prenom" name="prenom" type="text" required>
    <span class="help-popup" id="popup-2"> Pour ce champs veillez à n'utilisez que des lettres</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you